# How to stitch these two images with some Python code using OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-stitching, contrast

I have two images

**Image 1:**

[image: Image-1]

**Image 2:**

[image: Image-2]

I tried various approaches but I got some errors. I also tried [this approach](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/17/image-stitching-with-opencv-and-python/). So, can we stitch these two images? If so, how can I do this in Python3?

Comment: Please share the code (and errors) of the approach(es) you have tried, so we can help you further.

Comment: It seems the stitcher cannot find the overlapping between the two images and that may cause the error.

Answer (score 2):

What would be your error? I tested using your images and it indeed produces error because OpenCV Stitcher cannot find the overlapping features between the two images. You can try to other images with at least 25% overlapping between the two images and use the simpler code for image stitching below.

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")
tupleImages=(img1,img2)
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(True)
result = stitcher.stitch(tupleImages)
cv2.imshow('result',result[1]) 
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff # press ESC to exit
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try using the images below [image: house2][image] and the result would be[image]